# Event not triggered

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, events

i have used a aspx page with vb code. the page is not firing any event after some time if the page is kept idle.

any property needs to set in page attribute??

any iis settings i should update

How to solve the issue

Comment: How long do are we talking about here? And what events in particular aren't being fired?

Comment: any event.. like button,lnkbutton... any events are not fired.. any iis problem?

Comment: ya.. in local if i debug its working fine.. but wen published it is showing this issue

Comment: Upon clicking one of the buttons does the page still post back yet the event doesn't fire or does the page just sit there?

Comment: Sounds like some JS code in the page is messing with the ASP.NET client side post back code - can you please give link to the live website so we can check this?

Comment: By the way, @Ranjana - when you post reply to comment use the `@` to notify the person you reply to, otherwise there's big chance he will never see you replied.

Answer (score 0):

Based on just what you posted I would guess your session is timing out.  I'm pretty sure that will break viewstate/postback functionality.

Please post your web.config `<system.web><sessionState>` configuration section, both for development and production.

Also you implied everything works fine if you postback right away, but if you load a page, wait X minutes, then postback, you get no postback event firing.  We need to know what X is and if it is a consistent number of minutes.

Edit: If this is in fact a session timeout issue, the default session timeout is 20 minutes.  Does this seem to line up with your problem?